# Can I fire `override` method in parent and grand-parent classes of base "virtual" method

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, virtual

i.e. I have 2-step inherited class, and have access  only `Parent_1` class:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void hello (){}
}

//
public class Parent_1 : Base
{
    public override void hello (){ Print("Hi 1"); }
}

public class Parent_2 : Parent_1
{ 
    public override void hello (){ Print("Hi 2");  xyz =123; } 
}
```

I don't have access to any code other than `Parent_1`. I want, when `Parent_2`'s `hello` is executed, my `Parent_1`'s `hello` was also fired.

I think there should exist some way, so when `Parent_2` is executed, somehow I got notified (event handler or whatever) in `Parent_1` , is not that possible?  I know `xyz` is "changed" there, so maybe a "property change observer" ?

Comment: Put `base.Hello();` in `Parent_2`'s `hello` method.

Comment: _"I don't have access to Parent_2", what you mean? You can't change its code?

Comment: With the information you have given us, the answer is 'No, you can't easily do that'. Depending on the exact details of the types involved, you may be able to write your own `ConvertFromParent_2ToParent_1` function, which you can use to create a new `Parent_1` from an instance of `Parent_2` and then invoke the function on that new instance. It is hard to know whether that is useful to your specific context.

Comment: No you can't, of course if your `hello` method changes something, that you have access to, you can somehow check if changes were made, call `hello` from `Parent_1`, but if it is as you have described, you can't without accessing (adding some code) class `Parent_2`.

Comment: @SeM thanks, all i know is that `Parent_2`'s hello is called when a base property named `xyz` changes.

Comment: @T.Todua Well, if you can create an event which will register changes on `xyz` it may do the trick (if only `hello` from `Parent_2` is changing `xyz`).

Comment: @T.Todua How did you go with the reflection based approach mentioned in the duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

> unfortuantely that doesnt help in my case, because I neither control
> other parts of code, neither main() like executions... I am just
> writing a module for existing app, which only uses my Parent_1 as
> intermediate between Parent_2 and Base

You can't and there is no way to do this I know (not even with reflection), *Polymorphism* in C# actually guarantees that the overridden method will be called unless you tell it to do so in the overridden method with `base`

## Original

If I understand what you are describing, overriding won't fire the base method unless you explicitly tell it to do so.

```
public class Parent_2 : Parent_1
{ 
    public override void hello ()
    { 
       base.hello();
       Print("Hi 2"); 
    }
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)

> Base classes may define and implement virtual methods, and derived
> classes can override them, which means they provide their own
> definition and implementation. At run-time, when client code calls the
> method, **the CLR looks up the run-time type of the object, and
> invokes that override of the virtual method. Thus in your source code
> you can call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's
> version of the method to be executed**.

[base (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base)

> The base keyword is used to access members of the base class from
> within a derived class:
>
> - **Call a method on the base class that has been overridden by another method.**
> - Specify which base-class constructor should be called when creating instances of the derived class.

---

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void hello()
    {
    }
}

//
public class Parent_1 : Base
{
    public override void hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi 1");
    }
}

public class Parent_2 : Parent_1
{
    public override void hello()
    {
        base.hello();
        Console.WriteLine("Hi 2");
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Parent_1 p = new Parent_2();
    p.hello();
}
```

**Output**

```
Hi 1
Hi 2
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dm2aCi)

Comment: @T.Todua i just demonstrated this with  `base.hello();`.. updated to show this

Comment: @T.Todua updated

Comment: I think another vector could be to monitor a `property` change? I've updated question. Is that possible way?

Comment: @T.Todua no all this requires that the instantiated class is programmed to do so.. there could be .net injection techniques however this is going to be a lot more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Well why can't you call base class one using the `base` keyword

```
public class Parent_2 : Parent_1
{         
    public override void hello (){ base.hello(); Print("Hi 2"); }        
}
```